# Combination of schedules for 5 days

Tags: combinatorics

I need help with a problem. I need to find the number of possible combinations to combine work schedules as follows :
No. of workdays : $5$ (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thurs, Fri)
One employee can work for two different employers : 
$2$ days for Employer $1$ + $2$ days for Employer $2$
OR 
$2$ days for Employer $1$ + $3$ days for Employer $2$

How many different combinations of schedules can be there?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Do you have any of your own thoughts about this problem?

Comment: You need to work for 5 days or you can work less than 5 days? And you  have only two employers?

Answer (score 0):

For the first possible work schedule, there are 5 possible days the person can work and the Employer wants them to work for 2 days. So there are 5 choose 2 days for the first employer that work. For the second employer only 3 days remain as two have already been chosen by the first employer. So there are 3 choose 2 ways of fulfilling the second Employer's wishes. You then multiply them together to get the total number of ways the first option is satisfied. For the second option the process is exactly the same but the second employer wants 3 days this time so he must choose 3 days from the remaining three. The total therefore is the summation of these two options.
$5 \choose 2$ * $3 \choose 2$ + $5 \choose 2$ * $3 \choose 3$

Comment: Did you mean $\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{3}$?